# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured for firefox driver

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Getting error as java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:63) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.7.2.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]

1.Added jp@gc - Firefox Driver Config and also added path is C:\Users\Bhaskara-Reddy\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.32.2-win32\geckodriver.exe.

jmeter version is 5.5, firefox version is 111.0 (64-bit), java version is 1.8.0_3612, jmeter plugin manager 1.8

Could anyone please help me how to configure firefox driver to jmeter steps to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your WebDriver Sampler plugin to version [4.8.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/4.8.1) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager) and see if the issue still occurs.

If this doesn't help - perform clean JMeter and Selenium Plugin installation.

If this doesn't help - check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

I can only state that I cannot reproruce your issue given I have WebDriver Sampler and the Firefox Driver Config in the same Thread Group and at the [same level](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)